# How to extract wkt string from kml file C#

Tags: c#, linq, kml, arcgis-runtime-net

So I’m trying to use ArcGIS Runtime to import and export kml files from a basic map control. I have the export working and I only now have to extract data from the kml file to draw a geometry on the map control.

I am only supporting line, points and polygons. Also single geometries only.

Do I simply try and use linq expressions to walk through the kml file and extract what I need? For example, if it’s a line, point or polygon and then create the WKT string from the coordinates and the shape information? I don’t want to use any third party tools but I can seem to see any relevant examples in the ArcGIS Runtime .NET examples.

Comment: Is there a reason you’re not just using the KmlLayer ?

Comment: @dotMorten is there something I’m missing that is already built in to help solve this problem?

Comment: Well that depends on what your problem is. Import and export of KML is supported in the SDK. You don't need to mess with WKT strings at all. There are KmlLayer and KmlDataset to do a lot of these things. You'll basically just create them pointing to a file or url and add them to your map.